# Change SQLAlchemy model column type on-the-fly

Tags: python, json, sqlite, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem - I use custom JSON type for postgresql dialect. 
I need to use both postgres/sqlite (postgres for production, sqlite for unit tests as a in-memory test database).

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.json import JSON


class Entity(ModelBase, SAModel):
   __tablename__ = 'entities'

  id = Column(pkey_type, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
  priority = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
  tags = Column(JSON, nullable=False, default={})
```

Unfortunally sqlite doesn't work with JSON directly. I need smth like a "SmartJSONType" which will switch behaviour based on current sqlalchemy dialect (work with JSON as as native Postgres JSON datatype and string in SQLite).
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So do you need help with emulating the behavior of the `JSON` dialect using just `String` columns and SQLite, or with doing the switch between the two implementations, or both?

Comment: are you really sure you want that?  The main benefit of using json in postgresql is the rich set of operators it provides for using json values in queries.  You won't get any of those in sqlite; just the unrelated and less useful string operators (which, in turn, aren't available on the postgresql JSON type).  If your only purpose is to *store* json data, just use `String` everywhere.

Comment: Oh, I'm aware that this is a very old question, but since I came across it trying to find the answer I thought I should come back and answer it for completeness :)

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do this. There is a [complete code example here](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/json.html).

But the simplified example would be:

```
class JSONType(sa.types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = sa.UnicodeText

    def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return dialect.type_descriptor(JSON())
        else:
            return dialect.type_descriptor(self.impl)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return value
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value)
        return value

   def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return value
        if value is not None:
            value = json.loads(value)
        return value
```

I do this myself because I run fast test in a sqlite in memory db, and slower tests in our actual production db which is postgres.